# Excel Formula Help Required- Multiple IF Formulas

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am looking to create a formula which will allow me to use a formula to categorize values into 6 different groups, the formula would need to return the group letter.

A= More than 800 units sold

B= Between 300-800 units sold

C= Between 200-300 units sold

D= Between 160- 200 Units Sold

E= Between 1- 160 Units Sold

F= Zero Units Sold

I have attached an example of the data I am working with:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XB5N.png)

I have tried the below formula with no luck

=IF([@[Sales]]<=1, "F",IF(AND([@[Sales]<=160, [Sales]]>1),"E",IF(AND([@[Sales]]<=200, [@[Sales]]>=160)),"D",IF(AND([@[Sales]]<=300,[@Sales]]>=201),"C", IF(AND([@[Sales]]<=301,[@[Sales]]>=800),"B","A"))))

This is not a Duplicate, must more information needed, before I was after 3 groups now I am after 6 groups now and the previous question's answer does work on in this case

Comment: This is not a Duplicate, must more information needed, before I was after 3 groups now I am after 6 groups

Comment: This really is a duplicate of your previous question. Excel formulas are not some arcane art that only wizards understand. You already have all the information needed from your last question to construct the 6 group formula.

Comment: =IF(Sales<100, "A", IF(Sales <1000, "B", "C"))
Is the formula I used for the previous question? 
When I tried to use this information to help me with this question, I attempted to use the following formula 
=IF([@[Sales]]<=1, "F",IF(AND([@[Sales]<=160, [Sales]]>1),"E",IF(AND([@[Sales]]<=200, [@[Sales]]>=160)),"D",IF(AND([@[Sales]]<=300,[@Sales]]>=201),"C", IF(AND([@[Sales]]<=301,[@[Sales]]>=800),"B","A"))))
But it keeps coming up with there’s a problem with this formula.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use AND():

`=IF([@[Sales]]>800,"A",IF([@[Sales]]>300,"B",IF([@[Sales]]>200,"C",IF([@[Sales]]>160,"D",IF([@[Sales]]>0,"E","F")))))`

Say [@[Sales]]=350. Because it reaches the second IF(), it has to be < 800. Similar logic applies to the other IF()'s.

Comment: When I do this I get an error message saying the formula is missing an opening or closing parenthesis

Comment: I then Changed it to =IF([@[Sales]]>800,"A",IF([@[Sales]]>300,"B",IF([@[Sales]]>200,"C",IF([@[Sales]]>160,"D",IF([@[Sales]]>0,"E","F")))) and then it says you've entered too many arguments for this function

Comment: That just means the () don't match up.  I'm on an iPad and can't test this, but see the formula above.  The number of open and close parentheses must be the same.

Answer (score 1):

I have Used IFS instead:

=IFS([@[Sales]]>800,"A",[@[Sales]]>300,"B",[@[Sales]]>200,"C",[@[Sales]]>160,"D",[@[Sales]]>1,"E",[@[Sales]]>0,"F", [@[Sales]]=0, "F")

Comment: That will work, too. Good on you. You have an extra "F", though..

Comment: Yes, i did notice that I didn't require it after I was double checking the results. i have removed it and made the first F <0